# Subsetting Rcpp::DateVector using IntegerVector that contains indices? Operator [] overload

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Rcpp Users,

I am new to Rcpp. I would like to subset a `DateVector` using an `IntegerVector` that has the integer indices. However, a direct use of `[]` leads to error message:

```
no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'Rcpp:DateVector'.
```

Here is an illustrate example:

In cpp file - dv.cpp:

```
#include < Rcpp.h >

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame subsetDateVector1(DataFrame df) {

  DateVector    dv = df["dv"];
  IntegerVector iv = df["iv"];

  for (int i = 0; i < dv.size(); i++) {
    dv[i] = dv[i] + 7;
  }

  IntegerVector idx = seq_len(2) - 1;

  // DateVector dv1 = dv[idx]; 
  // Q: cannot subset DateVector using IntegerVector? 
  // Any Reason? 
  // How to work around, efficiently?

  // my work around
  Function formatDate("format.Date");
  CharacterVector dvc(dv.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < dv.size(); i++) {
    dvc[i] = as<std::string>(formatDate(wrap(dv[i])));
  }
  CharacterVector dv1 = dvc[idx];

  IntegerVector iv1 = iv[idx];

  return (DataFrame::create(_["dv"] = dv1, _["iv"] = iv1));

}
```

In R file - dv.r:

```
# subsetting Rcpp::DateVector [Ex]

source("dv.cpp")

dv = Sys.Date() + -2:2

iv = 1:5

df = data.frame(dv = dv, iv = iv)

> df
          dv iv
1 2015-12-06  1
2 2015-12-07  2
3 2015-12-08  3
4 2015-12-09  4
5 2015-12-10  5

> subsetDateVector1(df)
          dv iv
1 2015-12-13  1
2 2015-12-14  2
```

I felt that the work around in `subsetDateVector1` is not very efficient.

Any reason that `DateVector dv1 = dv[idx];` not being implemented?

Any efficient way to take subset on `DateVector` based on indices?

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2):

DateVector and DatetimeVector are a little apart in Rcpp and survive from the very earliest days (when they were accessed from RQuantLib).  They should probably be deprecated and replaced by something better, but I have not yet gotten to that.

You can just work with the *numeric* Date (or Datetime) values in a `NumericVector` which also gives you the subsetting you want.  The Rblpapi package has some examples---in essence I just place the `POSIXct` equivalent of fractional seconds since epoch into a `NumericVector` and then reclass it later to `POSIXct`.

Lastly, if I may, please don't do

```
  Function formatDate("format.Date");
  CharacterVector dvc(dv.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < dv.size(); i++) {
    dvc[i] = as<std::string>(formatDate(wrap(dv[i])));
  }
```

You can perfectly well format dates and times in C++. It is worth learning that.

Comment: Thank you, Dirk. And, thank you for your advice on the way of formatting dates. I learned the trick as<std::string>(formatDate(wrap(dv[i]))); for converting Dates to Strings from RcppExamples. I guess I need to dig into C++ dates library for well designed formatting methods? - I did not found a dedicated topic on dates in "Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp (Use R!)". Thanks again for providing such a great interface between R and C++.